# Duplicate mail with mail_interceptor in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, interceptor

I have set up a mail interceptor, but I can't make it duplicate the email as I'd like.

```
class MailDuplicator
  def self.delivering_email(message)

    copy = message
    copy.subject = "[Duplicata] To: #{message.to} - #{message.subject}"
    copy.to = "Logger <logs@email.com>"
    copy.deliver

    return message
  end
end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: don't use mail_interceptor, but mail_observer, which is called *after* the mail is sent.

```
# LIB (/lib/mail_duplicator.rb)
class MailDuplicator
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    duplicate_email = 'logs@email.com'

    if !message.to.include?(duplicate_email) # Avoid stack level too deep error
      message.subject = "[Duplicata] To: #{message.to} - #{message.subject}"
      message.to = duplicate_email

      message.deliver
    end

    return message
  end
end


# INITALIZER (/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb)
require 'mail_duplicator'
ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailDuplicator)
```

Though I still haven't managed to duplicate the `Mail::Message` object as I wanted to do at first ...